# How to use view-params with JSP?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, viewparams

I would like to use view parameters to get bookmarkable URLs with JSF 2, but I use JSPs and all the help and examples I can find, uses facelets. Here is want I have done so far:

search.jsp (calling page):

```
  <t:commandLink action="...">
      <f:param name="param1" value="foo"/>
      <h:outputText value="..."/>                  
  </t:commandLink>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
  <navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>go_edit</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/views/edit.jsp</to-view-id>
      <redirect>
        <view-param>
          <name>param1</name>
          <value>#{edit.param1}</value>
        </view-param>
      </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
```

Edit.java (edit page backing bean):

```
public class Edit extends ... {

  private String param1;

  public String getParam1(){
    return param1;
  }

  public void setParam1(String param1){
    this.param1 = param1;
  }

  ...
}
```

I think the problem is, that I didn't add the view params to the edit page (e.g. edit.jsp). I only found facelet examples, which look like this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</f:metadata>
```

My question is, can I use JSP view params? Can someone provide or point me to an complete example? Especially the part with the target page (e.g. edit.jsp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. JSP is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) since JSF 2.0 in December 2009 (almost 4 years ago already!). All new JSF 2.x specific tags are available to [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/) only and not to [JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/jsp/). Basically, with JSP you've only JSF 1.x specific tags available. In other words, the JSF 2.x tags `<f:metadata>`, `<f:viewParam>`, `<f:ajax>`, `<h:head>`, `<h:outputScript>`, etc are **not** available to JSP.

There's no point working with deprecated technology. It's high time to [migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870).

Comment: Well, not the answer I hoped for, but an answer nonetheless. Thanks! The thing is, the application is more than 7 years old and contains more than 1000 JSPs, custom components, etc. We gonna migrate eventually, but I had hoped I could get bookmarkable URLs working in the near future.